# Printing out image in matlab for emphasizing different values

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement K-NN with a training set of 4 different classes.
What I cannot figure out is how can I show and emphasize in a gray scale image
if I get the the image as a matrix below A

1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1

.................................

.................................

1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0

So what I want is a image that exhibit different color for different values of 0,1,2,3
I am trying to do it with 
imshow(A,[min max]), but I get just back, gray and white, I don't get 4 different colors.
can please someone help me out.

Thank you in advance

Rinad

Answer (score 1):

try `imagesc(A); colorbar;`

it does automatic scaling to populate the colors.